# How to split String Data type separated with comma in a MS ACCESS database using a QUERY in vb.net

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010

I don't have idea how to split data using a query... I want to implement the split on the WhERE Clause because I am trying to select data Where the value of WHERE Clause is separated with comma

My sample Query

```
SELECT Name FROM Entry_time WHERE Edate = '"Combobox.selectedItem"'
```

I want that only the date

The Data value from database:
Fri, 02/21/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert to a DateTime, then to a formatted string expression for Access SQL:

```
Dim FilterDate As DateTime
Dim FilterText As String    
Dim Provider   As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

FilterDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Combobox.selectedItem.Text.Split(",")(1).Trim(), "MM'/'dd'/'yy", Provider)     
FilterText = FilterDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")

SQL = "SELECT [Name] FROM Entry_time WHERE Edate = #" + FilterText + "#"
```